# How do i keep jQuery Mobile styling on buttons etc. injected in the HTML by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile

I am using the jQuery mobile library trying to make a user-editable list of checkboxes. A snippet of the HTML code is presented beneath, and the ' fieldset id="nameList"...' is where i try to inject the checkboxes dynamically using the javascript function addName();

```
<div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <input type="submit" onclick="addName()" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-icon="plus" data-iconpos="left" value="Add New Name" />
                    <input id="textInput" placeholder="Enter a new name" value="" type="text" />
                </fieldset>
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <fieldset id="nameList" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
                    <legend>
                        Members
                    </legend>
                    <input name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
                    <label for="checkbox1">
                        Checkbox1
                    </label>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" data-inline="true" data-theme="e" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="left" value="Delete checked names" />
        </div>
```

I have tried to both put this function inside the HTML document itselt, and in a separate .js file, but it gives the same result either way, shown in the picture under the js code.

```
function addName(){
            $('#nameList').append('<input name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" />'+
                                '<label for="checkbox1">'+$('#textInput').val()+'</label><br>');
        }
```

The result after having added a ned checkbox to the already existing list of functioning checkboxes is just a un-styled checkbox instead of looking like the checkbox i coded directly in HTML, shown in this picture: http://bildr.no/view/1134640

It seems to mee that for some reason the jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css simply does not style jQuery Mobile code that is added using javascript. I have had this problem before with other things that checkboxes, also different types of jQuery Mobile buttons won't appear as they should when added by javascript. Is there any way to add HTML code from javascript and still get all the benefits of the jQuery Mobile css?

Answer (score 1):

You have to trigger the `create` event on the item or one of it's ancestors in order for jQuery Mobile to add the appropriate markup and classes to get it styled.

```
function addName(){
    var lastID = $('[name^="checkbox"]').attr('name')
                                        .replace(/^checkbox/,''),
        nextID = parseInt(lastID,10) + 1;
    $('#nameList').append('<input name="checkbox"'
                          + nextID + ' id="checkbox"'
                          + nextID + ' type="checkbox" />'
                          + '<label for="checkbox'
                          + nextID + '">'+$('#textInput').val()
                          + '</label><br>')
                  .trigger('create');
}
```

See the section *Enhancing New Markup* at http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

FWIW - you'll need to modify the id of the checkbox as ids need to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

After adding the dynamic checkbox, call

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").checkboxradio();
```

EDIT: Removed 'refresh' as parameter to checkboxradio.  Maybe this will help someone else in the future.

Comment: That did not work for me, i just got this error message: 

Uncaught cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'


When i changed the calling to this nothing happened:     $("nameList[type=checkbox]").checkboxradio('refresh');

Comment: Hmm, I'm sorry that didn't work for you.  Maybe you just needed to call .checkboxradio() with no parameters to "create" it the first time.  Or maybe instead of 'refresh', you use 'create'.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile applies the styles with JavaScript, so dynamically added content must be parsed to add the styles. jQuery Mobile provides the function `.page()` to apply styles to newly created content

So after adding that, you could use:

```
$('input').page();
```

Or use a class like `newclass` with those newly added elements, so jQuery doesn't have to parse all the inputs every time you add one

More information: http://jquerymobiledictionary.pl/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

if you are adding checkbox like this

```
enter code here
   @foreach (var selectListItem in Mobile.GetLookupAsSelectList(Shared.TableConstants.FiledName))
            {

             <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-@selectListItem.Value" class="fillter" id="@selectListItem.Value" value="@selectListItem.Value"/>
                  <label for="@selectListItem.Value">
                   @selectListItem.Text</label>
            }
```

Make sure your input